# Removing Rows in R Has Distorted the Data Set

Tags: r, rows, regression, lmer

I have removed certain rows from my database using the following code:

```
df2 <- df1[!(df1$variable==1), ]
```

This was a dummy variable, and the rows that had the value of 1 for that particular dummy variable were successfully removed. (I checked the dimensions of my database using the "dim" function before and after; and everything seemed normal.)

However, after I ran my regression model this time with the new data set "df2", I saw that the degrees-of-freedom had fallen sharply! This was way over the number of the removed rows!

I wondered how this could happen. Then, I realized that the new data set had many rows that had NAs only. At each row that the random variable had a missing value, R had made a full row of NA values.

After realizing that the above code was not the best way to delete rows, I tried the following:

```
df2 <- df1[(df1$variable==0 | is.na(df1$variable)), ]
```

It seems to have worked, since I no longer have the same problem. But would you say that this new code above may have some (similar or other) problems that I am not really aware of right now?

Comment: You'll probably have to show us more information, like (1) Full code for the first and second regression models; (2) output of `table(df$variable)` before and after the subsetting; (3) `dim(df)` from before and after.

Comment: Please check `class(evs27m$muslim)` or even better post the output of `dput(head(evs27m))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new code should be fine.  The problem with the old code was caused by a combination of the `NA`s in `df1$variable` and the `==` comparison operator.

If you read the help on comparison operators, `?"=="`, you will see, 
"*Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA.*"

In your case, whenever the df1$variable was `NA`, the results of your attempted subset was `NA` (not `TRUE` or `FALSE`), which caused the other variables in the row to be `NA`.  For example:

```
df1 <- expand.grid(variable=c(0, 1, NA), var2=c(0, 1, NA))

sel1 <- !(df1$variable==1)
sel1
df1[sel1, ]

sel2 <- df1$variable==0 | is.na(df1$variable)
sel2
df1[sel2, ]
```